# Editing ASPX files in Visual Studio 2010 have no effect while debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I debug a Visual Studio 2010 web application project, any changes to ASPX files have no effect - the pages are not recompiled. Edits in code-behind works as usual.

I recently switches to Windows 7 64-bit (from 32 bit), but if I'm not crazy editing ASPX files worked in the 64 bit environment a few days ago.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel).

I have tried all the combinations of "Edit and Continue", "Break all processes when one process breaks" and "Require the source file to exactly match the original version" I can think of, but nothing seems to work.

I'm using IIS Express as web server (Use Local IIS Web Server / Use IIS Express) and have done so even when it was working.

Thankful for any advice!

Comment: Are you pressing save after making the changes? It's sometimes easy to forget this when debugging as Visual Studio saves the files before building the website - is there a * in the tab name for the ASPX you are editing. The only other thing I can think of is that your ASPX are being copied somewhere else during build, but you mentioned that code behind changes are applied, so...

Comment: Yes, I am pressing save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had manually set a registry setting (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode = 1) to try to fix another issue with UNC virtual folders. That flag disables File Change Notification also on local files. I had completely forgot about this flag, but it is of course the obvious cause for my problem.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pressing Ctrl+F5 on your keyboard? This should request the latest page from the server as opposed to using the cached page in the browser.

Comment: Same comment as above - I have tried to refresh the page with Ctrl-F5, cleared the cache and even opened up a different browser (FF instead of IE), but no edits are not shown anywhere.

Comment: It happens also when I use "Start without debugging" and edit the ASPX files manually.

Answer (score 0):

on the broswer u are using Press `Cntrl+F5`
after you edited the `.aspx` file

Comment: Forgot to mention that - I have tried to refresh the page with Ctrl-F5, cleared the cache and even opened up a different browser (FF instead of IE), but no edits are not shown anywhere.